# Could not load type 'PROCESS_DPI_AWARENESS' from assembly 'WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0,

Tags: c#, windows, exception, dpi, unhandled-exception

I have added DPI awareness for the app using this manifest file:

```
 <application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
       <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
       <dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">PerMonitorV2</dpiAwareness>
    </windowsSettings>
  </application>
```

It works mostly but on one of the client machines exception is thrown:

```
Could not load type 'PROCESS_DPI_AWARENESS' from assembly 'WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0,
```

In my code `PROCESS_DPI_AWARENESS` variable is not used. `System.WindowsBase` is added as dependancy to my project.

I use DPI on several windows using this:

```
 var dpi = VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi(this);
```

Could you hint how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: [It should be there](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Shared/MS/Win32/NativeMethodsCLR.cs,7335), ensure that you set the target .NETFramework version high enough so the user can't run without an outdated version.

Comment: @HansPassant unfortunately user machine .NETFramework version is 4.8

Comment: Getting that machine healthy again is a job for the user's IT staff.